# Javascript replace error in Safari on some sites

Tags: javascript, safari

If you go to https://www.artistguitars.com.au on safari 12 ,open console and enter:

```
x='%str%';
x.replace (/%str%/g, '$15');
```

you will get '5' instead of $15

On other browsers it works well.

Why is that? I could not find information anywhere.

Comment: I can't reproduce this...it gives me `$15` as expected

Comment: @b001 Here is a screenshot: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3815624/a9d9c7dfb4560aefc8c01ffce94a2ea4